# pie chart percentage with ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, percentage, pie-chart

I am new in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor). I follow this [Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) for creating a Pie Chart.
so I use this code

```
@{   var myChart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 400, theme: ChartTheme.Green)
    .AddTitle("Pourcentage des réservations par catégorie")
    .AddSeries(
           name: "Ressources réservées",
           chartType: "Pie",
           xValue: new[] { "Hebergement", "Repas", "Espace", "Service", "Produit" },
           yValues: new[] { temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6 })
    .Write();
}
```

My Pie chart is created, but I don't know how to show **percentages** and **values**.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about creating chart in Razor View page but this could help you where I create chart in  controller's action method

```
  public ActionResult GetPieChart()
    {
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());

        chart.Series.Add(new Series("Data"));
        chart.Series["Data"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;            
        double[] yValues = { 71.15, 23.19, 5.66 };
        string[] xValues = { "LABLE1", "LABLE2", "LABLE3" };

        chart.Series["Data"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues,yValues);
        chart.Series[0].Label = "#VALX #PERCENT{P0}"; // THIS IS TO GET THE PERCENTAGE
        //Other chart formatting and data source omitted.

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
    }
```

Comment: My above code is at the view folder (index.cshtml), so I don't know how to do the same thing in the controller (indexController.cs).